# remove dynamically attached event Listeners to elements

Tags: javascript

I have these event listeners attached to an element dynamically like this:

```
const allTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.question-title');
allTitles.forEach(title => {
   title.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      // some code goes here using e above
   });
});
```

How can we remove all attached event listeners? As we have no reference to each listener and it's function this seems a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the event listener to the parent element of all your objects and listen for clicks on the parent element

```
parentElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     console.log(e.target) // this will be your title if you click on that, otherwise you can just return a falsy value
})
```

Comment: Event delegation is indeed good practice, but how this answers question about removing anonymous listener? This just changes many "nondetachable" listeners to single "nondetachable" listener.

Comment: @myf indeed, the case specified by the user does not seem to need a detachable event, considering that he wants all the titles to be clickable. He could probably attach and detach the event based on the hovering of the mouse over the parent element, but that does seem like an overkill

Answer (score 1):

Store the event listener in a variable. Then you can remove it with removeElementListener.

```
var listeners = [];
allTitles.forEach(title => {
   var listener = (e) => {
      // some code goes here using e above
   });
   title.addEventListener("click", listener);
   listeners.push(listener);
});
```

Then, you can remove a listener like this:

```
title.removeElementListener(listeners[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the same way you added them, but using `removeEventListener`. Try giving the function you used to add to them a name first, and then do something like this

```
allTitles.forEach(title => {
  title.removeEventListener("click", onClickFunction});
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: without reference to event handler, we can't. At least not elegantly.

The only working but brute-force option is to throw away original element with attached listener and re-create it from scratch.  Re-assigning `outerHTML` does that:

```js
allTitles.forEach(title => {
  title.outerHTML = title.outerHTML; // nuke listeners
});
```